# Fill in missing properties in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

What is the best way to fill in missing properties in an array of objects, such as this example:

```
[
    {
        name: 'Tom',
        number: '01234 567 890',
        website: 'http://www.tom.com'
    },
    {
        name: 'Richard',
        number '07777 666 555'
    },
    {
        name: 'Harry',
        website: 'http://www.harry.com'
    }
]
```

I need to add the missing properties with a null value, so that when I pass this array on to be rendered in something such as a HTML table or CSV file, everything lines up correctly. I was thinking of passing over the array twice, once to get all the possible properties, and a second time to add those missing properties with a null value to each object where it doesn't exist. Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT: I won't know what the keys are until I have the data, it's coming from an API and the keys are not always requested explicitly.

---

### My final solution

Thanks all, it seems the two pass approach is indeed the best approach. After I started to write this using the examples provided, I realised that the order of the properties wasn't being maintained. This is how I achieved filling in the missing props, and maintaining the correct order. Any suggestions for potential improvements are welcome.

```js
var fillMissingProps = function(arr) {
    // build a list of keys in the correct order
    var keys = [];
    arr.forEach(function(obj) {
        var lastIndex = -1;
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key, i) {
            if (keys.includes(key)) {
                // record the position of the existing key
                lastIndex = keys.lastIndexOf(key);
                if (lastIndex < i) {
                    // this key is in the wrong position so move it
                    keys.splice(i, 0, keys.splice(lastIndex, 1)[0]);
                    lastIndex = i;
                }
            } else {
                // add the new key in the correct position
                // after the previous existing key
                lastIndex++;
                keys.splice(lastIndex, 0, key);
            }
        });
    });

    // build a template object with all props set to null
    // and in the correct position
    var defaults = {};
    keys.forEach(function(key) {
        defaults[key] = null;
    });

    // and update the array by overwriting each element with a
    // new object that's built from the template and the original object
    arr.forEach(function(obj, i, arr) {
        arr[i] = Object.assign({}, defaults, obj);
    });

    return arr;
};

/** TEST **/

var currentArray = [
    {
        website: 'http://www.unknown.com'
    },
    {
        name: 'Tom',
        number: '01234 567 890',
        website: 'http://www.tom.com'
    },
    {
        title: 'Mr',
        name: 'Richard',
        gender: 'Male',
        number: '04321 666 555'
    },
    {
        id: '003ABCDEFGHIJKL',
        name: 'Harry',
        website: 'http://www.harry.com',
        mobile: '07890 123 456',
        city: 'Brentwood',
        county: 'Essex'
    }
];

var newArray = fillMissingProps(currentArray);

for (var i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
    for (var prop in newArray[i]) {
        console.log(prop + ": " + newArray[i][prop]);
    }
    console.log('---------');
}
```

Comment: Or you could just pass over it once, when you render it and pass in `null` (or whatever) for the keys you don't have.

Comment: do you not know apriori which keys are supposed to exist ?

Comment: Do you have a genuine need to support arbitrary properties? If not, use `Object.assign` with a default object that has all the keys. If you do, then you'll have to get all the keys, create a default object, then you could do the same thing.

Comment: I won't know what the keys are until I get the data.

Comment: @marktuk it seems you have no choice but to iterator over the array twice, then.

Comment: If you're getting the keys from server-side code you control then you could build up the keys there, but it's kind of six-of-one/half-dozen of the other.

Comment: @marktuk if you're using ES6 you can use a `Set` to more efficiently contain the list of keys - they preserve elements in "insertion order".  In older JS (ES5 or older) you can't rely on the key order of a plain object anyway, so in that sense your input is already non-deterministic so your attempt to preserve order is futile.

Comment: @marktuk actually, I *think* if you're using ES6 my code already suffices, since in ES6 object order is preserved.   If you're using ES5, object order is explicitly not ordered and you shouldn't rely on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that you don't know apriori which keys are supposed to exist, you have no choice but to iterate over the array twice:

```
// build a map of unique keys (with null values)
var keys = {}
array.forEach(el => Object.keys(el).forEach(k => keys[k] = null));

// and update the array by overwriting each element with a
// new object that's built from the null map and the original object
array.forEach((el, ix, a) => a[ix] = Object.assign({}, keys, el));
```

Comment: @DaveNewton unfortunately it seems you can't use `Object.assign(orig, keys, orig)` to update the properties in-place.

Comment: Right; duh, my bad.

Comment: @Alnitak this is definitely the best approach. I've updated above with my final solution based on this method.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const arr = [
  {
    name: 'Tom',
    number: '01234 567 890',
    website: 'http://www.tom.com',
  },
  {
    name: 'Richard',
    number: '07777 666 555',
  },
  {
    name: 'Harry',
    website: 'http://www.harry.com',
  },
];
const newArr = arr.map(x => (
  arr.map(x => Object.keys(x))
    .reduce((a, b) =>
      (b.forEach(z => a.includes(z) || a.push(z)), a)
    )
  .forEach(
    y => (x[y] = x.hasOwnProperty(y) ? x[y] : null)
  ), x)
);
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: So this is what I had in mind, but I would still need to do an initial pass over the array to get all the possible keys. I won't know what they are until I've done this unfortunately, and the array could be quite large.

Comment: OP does not know what keys will be.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all keys and set all keys using `for..of` loop, `.map()` to iterate all `Object.keys()`, redefine original array

```js
var arr = [{
  name: 'Harry',
  website: 'http://www.harry.com'
},{
  name: 'Tom',
  number: '01234 567 890',
  website: 'http://www.tom.com'
}, {
  name: 'Richard',
  number: '07777 666 555'
}];

for (var obj of arr) {
  for (var key of Object.keys(obj)) {
    arr = arr.map(o => (o[key] = o[key] || null, o))
  }
};

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: wuh?!  The one with the largest number of keys might have keys that are completely disjoint from the others.

Comment: @Alnitak What do you mean by "disjoint"?

Comment: The object with the greatest number of keys may not have all the properties that other objects with less number of keys do.

Comment: @Terry Still not sure what you mean? Can you share an example? The object at OP does not have the key present, or has the key present. Do you mean an array other than what OP expects and describes at Question?

Comment: One object may contain key1, key2, key3...keyN and another object may contain key(N+1). In this case the first object, even though having the greatest number of keys, does not contain any keys from the latter.

Comment: @Terry That is not what OP describes at Question?

Comment: OP's example does show that keys are not disjoint, but we cannot assume that it is true for the entire actual object. "If OP only gives me black cats, are all cats black?"

Comment: @Terry _""If OP only gives me black cats, are all cats black?""_ Yes. To that point those are the only cats present to account for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more interesting answer, its a tad fun one but it will build up your objects on the fly as new properties appear:

```js
var currentArray = [
    {
        name: 'Tom',
        number: '01234 567 890',
        website: 'http://www.tom.com'
    },
    {
        name: 'Richard',
        number: '07777 666 555'
    },
    {
        name: 'Harry',
        website: 'http://www.harry.com'
    }
]

var newArray = []

function NewObject() {

}

for(var i = 0; i < currentArray.length; i++){
  
  var nObj = new NewObject();
  
  for(var prop in currentArray[i]){   
    if(!NewObject.hasOwnProperty(prop))
        NewObject.prototype[prop] = null;
    nObj[prop]=currentArray[i][prop];   
  }
  
  newArray.push(nObj);
}

for(var i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++){
     for(var prop in newArray[i]){ 
         console.log(prop+ ": "+newArray[i][prop]);
     }  
    console.log('---------');
}
```

It builds new objects from the ones you provide and adds new properties to the objects if they don't exist already.

This idea was more for curiosities sake tho so any comments would be interesting :)

Comment: This is quite interesting, you've done it in a single pass of the array, very clever. I think this is my favourite solution, very elegant. I wonder if there are any caveats to this approach?

Comment: So one drawback I've found is the order of the properties is not maintained. You can see this if you run your example.

Comment: whilst cute, this method will break if you subsequently use any enumeration method that only includes an object's "own properties" and doesn't include those inherited from the prototype chain.

Comment: @Alnitak Yea I see, its all good, the idea behind this code was for curiosity and cuteness sake :)

Comment: @marktuk Yea I wouldn't use this I just wanted to see what was possible, and peoples opinions on it :) If you play with it more you may get it in a nicer state but I would definitely go with Alnitak's answer for stability's sake :)

Answer (score -1):

Something like this could work:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
   yourArray[i].name = yourArray[i].name || null;
   yourArray[i].number = yourArray[i].number || null;
   yourArray[i].website= yourArray[i].website|| null;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I won't know what the keys will be until I have the data.